# create random graph with "same" power-law degree distribution

Tags: r, igraph

I have an undirected graph (a Protein-Protein Interaction network, PPi) for which I know the degree distribution approximates a power-law distribution. I want to create 1,000 random graphs replicating the number of nodes, edges and "similar" power-law outdegree distribution.

My real graph `g.lcc` has:

```
> g.lcc
#IGRAPH UN-- 12551 166189 -- 
#+ attr: name (v/c), V3 (e/n)
```

What I did so far was:

```
#Calculate the alpha for my distribution
alpha <- power.law.fit(degree(g.lcc, mode="out"))
#$continuous
#[1] FALSE

#$alpha
#[1] 4.529602

#$xmin
#[1] 178

#$logLik
#[1] -1123.405

#$KS.stat
#[1] 0.0446421

#$KS.p
#[1] 0.7825008
```

Then I run `statitc.power.law.game` using as `exp.out` the alpha generated with `power.law.fit`:

```
random.g <- static.power.law.game(12551, 166189, 4.53, exponent.in=-1, finite.size.correction=T)
```

However when I do that the two distributions are not even similar...

Any help??

P.S attached two images with real.ppi and random.g

[image: Random graph] [image: Real PPI]

Comment: How do you know that the degree distribution of your PPI network approximates a power-law? It could be any other fat-tailed distribution as well. Also, the `$xmin` value of the resulting power law fit indicates that the best fit is achieved by a lower cutoff at degree=178 and whatever happens at degrees below 178 is not approximated by the exponent that the method fitted.

Comment: So, it is imposible to create random networks that approximates my degree distribution? Should I use the degree.sequence.game to create the random graphs? And a last question, how could I know my PPI network approximates a power law distribution and no any other? Many thanks in advance @Tamás

Comment: Just use `degree.sequence.game` to get random graphs with exactly the same degree distribution as your graph. Or use `rewire.edges` to rewire the edges of your graph (although I would go for `degree.sequence.game`). Re power laws, I recommend reading this paper first: http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062.pdf

Comment: @Tamás, if you write your comment as an answer I will award it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you know that the degree distribution of your PPI network approximates a power-law? It could be any other fat-tailed distribution as well. Also, the `$xmin` value of the resulting power law fit indicates that the best fit is achieved by a lower cutoff at degree=178 and whatever happens at degrees below 178 is not approximated by the exponent that the method fitted.

If you want to create a random network that has *exactly* the same degree distribution as your graph, you can try using `degree.sequence.game` to generate one from scratch (make sure you use `method="vl"` or `method="simple.no.multiple` if you want to avoid multiple edges between the same pair of nodes), or use `rewire.edges` to rewrite the edges of your graph.

Re power laws, I recommend reading [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062.pdf) about power-law-like distributions in empirical data.

Comment: I think fat-tailed distributions are always meant to follow power-law asymptotically. May be the better word is heavy-tailed distributions.